# Detecting the rmdir error with php

Tags: php, rmdir

rmdir() displays a few warnings like the dir does not exist, or permissions did not allow.  How can I capture which reason for failure and react to it?

Comment: If you have PHP 5.2.0 or greater, see [error_get_last()](http://php.net/error_get_last)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rmdir does not throw Exception so you cannot catch them with try/catch. What you can do is use [error_get_last](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) function to do what you need.

Try something like this:

```
if (!@rmdir('/root')) {
    $error = error_get_last();

    if (preg_match('/something/', $error['message'])) {
        // do something
    } elseif (preg_match('/somethingelse/', $error['message'])) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check beforehand if you are allowed to do some kind of action like `file_exists()` and `is_ dir()` to check if a directory exists and `fileperms()` or just `is_ writable()` to check if you can write a directory.

You can also try to "catch" the error like with exceptions. you can specify a custom error handler, but this seems to be a bit overkill.

Comment: Also, checking for an `empty(scandir($dir))` would help, as `rmdir` can't delete a non-empty directory. I usually just use `\`rm -rf $dir\``